# find and replace problem

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

i working on a carousel and i would like to add an additional functionality such that, when the user clicks on an image, thumbnail if you like, that image is replaced with a large image on a div above the carousel.

I managed to get to work with just one image. so no matter, the thumbnail clicked on, the large image remains the same, which is not ideal. Also, i have named my files like this test1_thumb, test1_large. So is there like a way to find the underscore and then replace the text which in this case is (thumb) with the large?

```
$('.carousel ul li').click(function() {    
    $('.content img').replaceWith('<img src="images/test_large.jpg"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to what you want to achieve :

$('.carousel ul li').click(function() {
    $('.content img').attr('src', urcurrentPath.replace('_thumb','_large');
});

Comment: $('.content img').attr('src', 'images'.replace('_thumb','_large')); thats what i did but it does not work?

Comment: 'images'.replace('_thumb','_large') Something is wrong here. I mean you should have some variable here holding the thumb url instead a string 'image'.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your thumbnail image in an anchor tag with the href pointing to the larger image, you'll simplify this process greatly.

```
$('.carousel a').click(function() {
    $('.content img').replaceWith('<img src="' + this.href + '"/>');
});
```